# 'NaTType' object has no attribute 'days'

Tags: pandas, missing-data

I have a column in my dataset which represents a date in ms and sometimes its values is `nan` (actually my columns is of type `str` and sometimes its valus is `'nan'`). I want to compute the epoch in days of this column. The problem is that when doing the difference of two dates:

```
(pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.to_datetime(np.nan)).days
```

if one is `nan` it is converted to `NaT` and the difference is of type `NaTType` which hasn't the attribute `days`.

In my case I would like to have `nan` as a result.

Other approach I have tried: `np.datetime64` cannot be used, since it cannot take as argument `nan`. My data cannot be converted to `int` since `int` doesn't have `nan`.

Comment: Why not just filter the column first: `df.loc[df['date'].notnull(), 'days'] = (pd.to_datetime('now') -df['date']).days`

Comment: I don't want to filter, I want to have all the entries, since actually I am creating a new column of my dataset. As I said I want `days=nan` as a result in these cases.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It will just work even if you filter first:

```
In [201]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[dt.datetime.now(), pd.NaT, dt.datetime(2015,1,1)]})
df

Out[201]:
                        date
0 2015-08-28 12:12:12.851729
1                        NaT
2 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000

In [203]:
df.loc[df['date'].notnull(), 'days'] = (pd.to_datetime('now') - df['date']).dt.days
df

Out[203]:
                        date  days
0 2015-08-28 12:12:12.851729    -1
1                        NaT   NaN
2 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000000   239
```

Comment: I agree with your solution, but I guess it would be better if `NaTType` had the attribute `days` (returning `nan`)

Comment: Not sure that makes much sense, it's an invalid value to me as opposed to a real DateTime object

Comment: with that feature your solution would be much simpler

Answer (score 2):

For me upgrading to pandas 0.20.3 from pandas 0.19.2 helped resolve this error.

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

Comment: YOU ARE LIFE SAVER!

Comment: Glad I could help :)